# Add text underneath circles for line with circles

Tags: html, css

How can I add text underneath these circles? For example, under 1, have it say Invite friends and under 2 write Custom T-shirt of your choice. [Codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/eGrOze)

I've found an [example](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/vOxwgm?editors=110) with text underneath but the issue is that it's fixed width and some of the text will be long so it's not a great solution.

```css
ul {
  text-align: justify;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

ul:before,
.active:after {
  content: '';
  width: 100%;
  border: 2px solid dodgerblue;
  position: absolute;
  top: 1em;
  margin-top: -2px;
  z-index: -1;
}

.active:after {
  border-color: lightblue;
}

ul:after {
  content: "";
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
}

li {
  width: 2em;
  height: 2em;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 2em;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: dodgerblue;
  margin: 0 1em;
  display: inline-block;
  color: white;
}

.active~li {
  background: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li class="active">4</li>
  <li>5</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is what you were looking for?

I added two `div`s under your `li` - one for the number, one for the content.  by breaking the `li` into being more of a marker, the control of child node css (margins and overflow especially) is easier to manage.

Then I split out `ul:before` and `active:after` to make them easier to manipulate as well.

You might want to do a diff on the CSS to see all of my changes.

Enjoy!

```css
ul {
  text-align: justify;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

ul:before {
  content: '';
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 1em;
  margin-top: -2px;
  border: 2px solid dodgerblue;
  z-index: -2;
}

li.active:after {
  content: '';
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 1em;
  margin-top: -2px;
  margin-left: 1em;
  border: 2px solid lightblue;
  z-index: -1;
}

ul:after {
  content: "";
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
}

li {}

ul li {
  display: inline-block;
}

ul li div.number {
  width: 2em;
  height: 2em;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 2em;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: dodgerblue;
  margin: 0 1em;
  color: white;
}

ul li div.under {
  position: absolute;
  top 2em;
  left: inherit;
}

.active~li {
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <div class="number">1</div>
    <div class="under">some text</div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="number">2</div>
    <div class="under">some more text</div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="number">3</div>
    <div class="under">even more text</div>
  </li>
  <li class="active">
    <div class="number">4</div>
    <div class="under"></div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="number">5</div>
    <div class="under"></div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: thanks. can you center the text? otherwise it looks messy. thanks

Comment: I kind of figured I'd leave the smaller cleanup details to you ... :)